# Some question on ranks of elements in a finite transitive closure

Tags: set-theory

So say given $x\in WF$, with the property tr cl$(x)$ is finite.

I want to say that any elements $z\in$ tr cl$(x)$ has finite rank.

This seems to be true (intuitively speaking), because the construction of tr cl$(x)$ basically involves collecting all descendants of $x$ and do a union on that collection. So if some members in the transitive closure has infinite rank (of some ordinal), then "we would have collected all it's infinite descendants and hence the closure cannot be finite"

So is my intuition correct ?

If no, are there any simple counter-examples ?

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: What is $WF$? What is transitive closure?

Comment: @copper.hat Those are very basic notions in set theory that can be expected to be known within the scope of this question. Hence, I think, they shouldn't be elaborated.

Comment: @StefanMesken: It would have been easier for you to write well founded than to write that you won't explain it.

Comment: @copper.hat If I had known that that's all you wanted to hear, I would have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to say that any elements $z\in$ tr cl$(x)$ has finite rank.

This is true. In fact

$$ \tag{$\dagger$}\mathrm{rank}_\in (\mathrm{trcl}(x))= \sup \{ \mathrm{rank}_\in (z) +1 \mid y \in \mathrm{trcl}(z) \}$$

Now, since $\mathrm{trcl}(x)$ is finite it follows (by an $\in$-induction) that $\mathrm{rank}_\in(\mathrm{trcl}(x))$ is finite and hence that, for any $z \in \mathrm{trcl}(x)$, $\mathrm{rank}_\in(z)$ is finite.

Finally $(\dagger)$ can be proved by an $\in$-induction over all sets in $\mathrm{WF}$, i.e. prove that for all $x \in \mathrm{WF}$
$$ \mathrm{rank}_\in(x) = \sup \{ \mathrm{rank}_\in(y) +1 \mid y  \in x \}.$$